# How to increase swap space on Ubuntu 20.04 ZFS?

Tags: ubuntu, swap, zfs

I have recently installed **Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS** as the file system. I check my RAM / swap and it is as follows:

```
qallaf89@desktop:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        22Gi       4.1Gi       1.9Gi       4.2Gi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Now if I want to increase my swap space normally I follow [this tutorial from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04) and it works perfectly. However, since I have ZFS I am having some issues:

```
qallaf89@desktop:~$ sudo fallocate -l 100G /swapfile
fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported
```

I looked around and indeed there seems to be a [problem with ZFS / fallocate()](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/326).

I also came across [this documentation from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1459/gizfl.html) but it is of no use to me as well:

```
qallaf89@desktop:~$ swap -l

Command 'swap' not found, did you mean:

  command 'stap' from deb systemtap (4.2-3)
  command 'szap' from deb dvb-apps (1.1.1+rev1500-1.2)
  command 'soap' from deb soapaligner (2.20-3)
  command 'sway' from deb sway (1.4-2)
  command 'smap' from deb slurm-client (19.05.5-1)
  command 'sswap' from deb secure-delete (3.1-6ubuntu2)
  command 'snap' from deb snapd (2.44.3+20.04)
  command 'swarp' from deb suckless-tools (44-1)
  command 'swab' from deb odin (2.0.3-2build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

qallaf89@desktop:~$ sudo apt show swap
N: Unable to locate package swap
N: Unable to locate package swap
E: No packages found
```

Could someone with knowledge on the matter please help me increase my swap space?

Comment: Is the swap area on a zfs volume  ?

Comment: This screenshot should show the full picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7v9ccmep8es31j/ubuntu%20zfs%20swap.png?dl=0

Comment: What is the output of 'zfs list' and 'swapon -s' ?

Comment: this is the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1fu7qz3juuy6ut/ubuntu%20zfs%20swap%20-%202.png?dl=0

Comment: A like for my answer, please.

Comment: I have marked it as the answer, when I upvote I get "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.". If there is another way let me know.

Comment: Sorry,  i'm not used to that.. asks more questions which is fair will improve your reputation. I will upvote the question itsel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This from the ArchWiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Swap_volume:

1. What do 'getconf PAGESIZE', ie the memory system's preferred memory page size ?
2. create a zfs volume for swap
3. prepare as swap
4. start the swap
5. mark it up as swap in etc/fstab (it is entirely possible that that is done automatically due to zfs properties.)

so:

```
zfs create -V 8G -b $(getconf PAGESIZE) \
          -o logbias=throughput -o sync=always\
          -o primarycache=metadata \
          -o com.sun:auto-snapshot=false rpool/swap
mkswap -f /dev/zvol/rpool/swap
swapon /dev/zvol/rpool/swap
```

I'm unsure about that logbias=thr.., primarycache=meta and '-o com.sun...' will do in your case, especially as the disk itself is an SSD. Either way, this will create a 8GB large zfs volume.

in etc/fstab:

```
/dev/zvol/rpool/swap none swap discard 0 0
```

With regards to ZFS: you should think and look for more disks, to gain  availability for the setup, you need to think about how to add mirroring.
If you loose the 1TB samsung ssd, the whole pool is toast.

With regards to sda5:
The [zpool administration section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-zpool.html) in FreeBSD's manual describes how to change an vdev into a mirroring pair.

In this case:

1. swapoff sda5
2. eventually clear the lable
3. reattach the vdev
4. wait for the resilver
5. add boot program

so:

```
swapoff /dev/sda5
zpool attach bpool sda5 sda6
```

And wait for the resilver.

Comment: I know I'm not using it properly at the moment, this is the first time. I need to gain more experience with it in order to benefit from its potential.

Comment: I followed the steps and everything seems good (https://www.dropbox.com/s/a15ue8ewvnmcxze/ubuntu%20zfs%20swap%20-%203.png?dl=0). But what about the old 2 GB partition, can I swapoff then delete or should I just keep it?

Comment: dev/sda5 ? You could test adding it to bpool ie turn bpool's vdev into a mirroring configuration.  The other disk's in the system, can you scrunge a 2 GiB partition somewhere there (preferably so that the vdev itself gets 3 partions.)

Comment: vdev is the term for zpool physical volumes (sort of...) A zpool is composed of vdevs

Comment: What do 'zpool list' say ?

Comment: This is link (updated): https://www.dropbox.com/s/0v5pa300qchexxu/ubuntu%20zfs%20swap%20-%204.png?dl=0

Comment: zpool, please. zpool is the command which creates zfs storage (ie zpools) and attaches, removes and rearranges storage.

Comment: But, yes the output from 'zfs list' were as i expected it to become.

Comment: Just updated the link with zpool output.

Comment: The FreeBSD handbook says a fair https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs-zpool.html

Comment: sorry 'zpool status', what you could try is changing bpool's vdev into a mirror, the idea then is to add partition from another disk to the same mirroring vdev.

Comment: This is the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdxbggj6oun3eg3/ubuntu%20zfs%20swap%20-%205.png?dl=0

Comment: The output from zpool says  that the pool is composed of a single vdev which implicitly is in a striping configuration.  You could reattach sda6 and sda5 in a mirroring pair.

Comment: Alright appreciate all the help, thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of "sync=always" better use "sync=standard" because there is an unsolved bug that causes hangs on swap zvols!

Comment: @PePa I used the above command line to create swap (and an ext4 for /var/lib/docker to avoid datasets hanging around https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41055) and ran into writeback_inodes task-hungs. Is this related to swap-zvol bug?

Comment: Options: `logbias=throughput`: Optimize writes for throughput, not latency. `primarycache=metadata`: Do not use FS cache for data blocks (would defeat the purpose of swapping). `sync=always`: Make all write requests synchronous (syscall only returns after block is on stable storage; not necessary, as if the system crashes, we no longer care about swap. Meant to reduce write latency? `standard` (default) or maybe even `disabled` is better). `com.sun:autosnapshot=false`: Optional `zfs-auto-snapshot` should ignore this volume (makes no sense for swap; could, if you use the volume for another FS).

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel This bug is unsolved, so just don't use swap on ZFS: https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/7734

Comment: @PePa Unfortunately, the standard Ubuntu 20.04 ZFS install creates only 2GB of swap and assigns the rest of the disk to ZFS. So I guess I have to steal swap back from ZFS for now, if I need more. And /var/lib/docker on ZFS also has its bugs: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41055

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it on a ZFS file system but on numerous others like ext3, ext3,ext4, XFS. Boot from a live USB stick, choose "Try Ubuntu without installing" and once up and running use `gparted` to resize partitions. You need to shrink one in order to free up space enough to enlarge the `swap` partition. This [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) is quite helpful, scroll down to "Using GParted". If you need a more comprehensive manual to gparted you [find one here](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual). Scroll down to "Resizing a Partition"

Comment: Looks kind of risky with ZFS, will try it as a last resort.

Comment: sda7, the zfs pool partition needs to be moved in that case - i don't trust gparted to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have previously used the [`systemd-swap`](https://github.com/Nefelim4ag/systemd-swap) package with some success (on arch only so far) - this can dynamically allocate swap files inside a directory as and when needed, so you don't need to reserve a large ZVOL inside your pool that will eat away at available space. I'm not sure how it does performance-wise, someone else could possibly provide more info than I could here, however, I've created a new filesystem and set the `com.sun:auto-snapshot` property to `false` as in the above - this prevents some utilities from creating snapshots, but only today I've realised that I still have snapshots from manual creation using `snapshot -r`, so I shall be looking for a better way to do this shortly! However in general you'll want to prevent any snapshot creation for this dataset, and tune it according to your scenario for speed and space tradeoff, if relevant. You'll then want to [point the systemd-swap config file](https://github.com/Nefelim4ag/systemd-swap/blob/master/include/swap-default.conf#L50) towards the mountpoint for this dataset.